# Apache and htpasswd getting errors from random number generator

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, htpasswd, random-number-generator

Recently (probably after yum update something), one of my CentOS7 server running Apache2.4.37 has started to produce the following errors.

```
apachectl configtest
(38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator

htpasswd -c -m ./htpasswd test
htpasswd: Unable to generate random bytes: Function not implemented
```

Obviously there are some trouble about random number generator, but I have never seen this problem and no idea about it.  I've been googling the past few days but could only find a few similar questions unanswered.  I confirmed that `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandam` exist and seem to be functioning.

I saw the source codes of Apache and htpasswd and assumed that `apr_generate_random_bytes` function in misc/unix/rand.c under apr is failing.  What is possible cause of this?

Comment: Where did you get Apache httpd from?

Comment: It is from pre-set VPS configurations. I'm inquiring with the company who manages the repository for updates. Meanwhile I’m wondering if I should uninstall this httpd to replace it with the one from the default CentOS repository, even though it is unsure that will fix the problem.

Comment: So you can't tell where it came from? Is it not from a repository? What sort of pre-set VPS is it?

Comment: It is from KUSANAGI RPM packages and I found out the URL: https://repo.prime-strategy.co.jp/rpm/noarch/kusanagi-httpd-2.4.37-1.noarch.rpm

Comment: Congrats, you've found a repository I never heard of before! Unfortunately I don't have any good advice on a better repo, (I switched happily to nginx long ago) but perhaps someone else will.